# Как уменьшить тень при нажатии на ImageButton?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imagebutton

Как уменьшить тень при нажатии на ImageButton?(сделать меньше теневой круг)

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bottom_menu_attachment"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю изменить размер `"?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` невозможно.

Как в папке drawable можете создать новый ресурс

```
<ripple
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

и установить его в качестве `background` для вашего элемента. Вместо формы `oval` можно использовать любую другую.

P.S. Если элемент к которому применяется кастомный `background` не является квадратом, то "тень" будет растянута и выглядеть как овал. Возможно это решается жестким указанием параметров  но это не точно. Зато точно можно задать исходный элемент квадратом с помощью android:layout_widht и an